# How to setup Atom JS autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, atom-editor

I'm trying to get **autocomplete** suggestions from my **Atom** code editor. When I'm trying `doc` I expecting `document` and when I typing `document.que` I'm expecting Atom would show me `.querySelector()`. And it's doesn't happening. I've installed these packages to resolve the issue:

- atom-ternjs

After that I still doesn't get autocomplete for `doc` or `document.` My -tern.project file looks like this:

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "libs": [],
  "loadEagerly": [],
  "dontLoad": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "doc_comment": true,
    "complete_strings": {
      "maxLength": 15
    },
    "node": {
      "dontLoad": "",
      "load": "",
      "modules": ""
    },
    "modules": {
      "dontLoad": "",
      "load": "",
      "modules": ""
    },
    "es_modules": {}
  }
}
```

So, how do you **autocomplete** JS in Atom? Interesting thing - notice if I create array and try `array.` then Atom gives me suggestions like .pop .push and others but why it doesn't give me a `document.` => `.querySelector()` and other for DOM manipulation.

My Atom config.cson:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "no"
  editor:
    fontSize: 13
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "bla-bla-bla"
  "linter-ui-default":
    showPanel: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. Need to activate:
Packages => Atom Ternjs => Configure Project => and here need to checkmark for **Browser** option.

Comment: Thanks. I really wish Atom had a more centralized support base that compiled simple questions\solutions such as this. I had to dig around a bit to find your post! As there was no solution on Atom's discussion board. Funny thing is, someone does have the question posted, but no solution was offered from the Atom experts... Annoying.